# What is the Javascript Regexp for finding the attributes in a <span> tags?

Tags: javascript, regex, html-sanitizing

I have a `<div contenteditable="true>` that I am trying to use to get text from users. I would use a simple `<textarea>`, but I need line-breaks and eventually lists and tables etc. I am trying to build something that is semi a rich-text editor, but not a full fledged one. I do not want to use a rich text editor.

I am trying to eliminate the attributes on `<span>` tags from the text that is typed into the `<div contenteditable="true>` . Is there a way to do that with Regexp? I was having difficulties coming up with a Regexp because I can't figure out how to make it so that the string starts with `<span` and ends with `>` and any number of characters can be in between. Is there a way to combine that in one Regexp? I came up with `/^<span >$/` but that does not work because there is no division between the two strings. Would something like this work: `/^[<span][>]$/g`?

Comment: if HTML is the input, regexps aren't the answer...

Comment: @Alnitak the input isn't HTML I have Javascript that retrieves the HTML. Basically what I am trying to work with is people who will copy text from web pages that is green and bolded etc. and paste it into  my `<div>`. I want to get rid of that styling when storing it.

Comment: If you're inexperienced with JavaScript, you may be overreaching yourself here.

Comment: @chromedude - that's still HTML

Comment: @Tim Down You're probably right. In some ways I see what you are saying, but in other ways I've got to learn sometime. Half a year ago I thought AJAX was cool, but only for those who were very skilled. For the past couple weeks I have been using AJAX quite often without a problem.

Comment: @chromedude: Fair enough, that attitude will get you a long way. With contenteditable, you will find  when you get into the details that there are a lot of niggly browser issues that may annoy you. One piece of advice: dealing with the editable content as a string of HTML is not going to work for anything but the most simple of cases. Learn DOM manipulation instead. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DOM functions for it. Here's some code using jQuery to make it easier and nicer to read:

```
$('#your-div span').each(function() {
    var elem = this, $elem = $(this);
    $.each(elem.attributes, function(i, attr) {
        if(attr) {
            $elem.removeAttr(attr.name);
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/qfsAb/

However, in your case you might want to remove attributes not only from spans but from all elements unless the attribute is e.g. `align` or `href`.

So, here's some JS for that: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/qfsAb/1/

```
$('#your-div').children().each(function() {
    var elem = this, $elem = $(this);
    $.each(elem.attributes, function(i, attr) {
        if(attr && attr.name != 'href' && attr.name != 'align') {
            $elem.removeAttr(attr.name);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this definitely does very what I asked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Parse the HTML** and then strip out the attributes afterwards. If you're doing this in a browser, you have a high grade HTML parser right at your disposal <sub>(or you have IE)</sub>, so use it!

Comment: Sorry, I'm relatively new to Javascript, and I am really not sure what parser I have in the browser. It's probably obvious I'm just confused.

Comment: @ThiefMaster o, ok I guess it was the way @nickf worded the question.

Answer (score 1):

I made a working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/b3DSQ/

```
$('#editor span').each(function(i, el) {
    var attrs = el.attributes;
    $.each(attrs, function(i, a) {
        $(el).removeAttr(a.name);
    });
});
```

[I changed an earlier version which copied the contents into memory, edited, and then replaced - hadn't realised that the stuff typed into the div was automatically valid in the DOM].

Comment: did you put the wrong url? Because it's coming up with an error when I go there.

Comment: yes, I did - the URL is now correct, but now refers to the earlier version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
your_string.replace(/<span[^>]*>/g, '<span>');
```

This will break however if the user writes something like `<span title="Go > there">`

Comment: Use the accepted answer, my answer only addresses the question that was asked directly but should not be used in this context.